# Java game with tiled map background problem

Tags: java, arrays, background, tile

I am trying to develop a Java 2D game and I have a problem with the tiled background. I am using the book *Developing Games In Java* as a tutorial but this part is insufficient so I need your help. The game map is based on a array

```
String fileName[]
{
   "wwwwwwwwwwww",
   "pppppppppppp",
   "oooooooooooo"
};
```

I try to place this array on a JFrame. After using a double for loop in order to read it and fill a specific image for each letter, I can see that no image is displayed. Is the way of thinking that I use correct or requires more? Please help

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to try to render the tiles in the JFrame.

Comment: Are you following to the letter the pattern of controlling the rendering yourself in the main loop of the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There was an error array out of bounds due to the fact that the the array width was 4 and the height was 3.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is that you are drawing your images at 1-pixel increments. You should probably be multiplying i and j by the width and height of a tile, respectively.

Additionally, you are loading your images once to cache them (in `loadImages()`), and then again on every single loop iteration. Very slow, and pointless.

Comment: Also, I can see that i have a very big mistake with the array because it is not 2d...